# SQL Server query that contains a derived table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, derived-table

I have created a select query that contains one regular table and two derived tables (subqueries). The derived tables are both joined with the regular table with left joins. The regular table contains over 7000 rows, but the query output is around 3000 rows. It has to be equal to the number of records in the regular table. What is my mistake?

```
SELECT T0.[ItemCode],
T0.[ItemName],
CASE T0.[PrcrmntMtd] WHEN 'B' THEN 'Inkoop' ELSE 'Productie' END AS Verwervingsmethode,
T0.[OnHand] AS Voorraad_excl_grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd] AS Grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
CASE WHEN T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd] IS NULL
THEN T0.[OnHand]
ELSE T0.[OnHand]-T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd]
END AS Voorraad_incl_grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
T2.[Nog_te_produceren] AS Geplande_productie_halffabrikaat_eindproduct,
T1.[Nog_te_produceren] AS Gereserveerd_voor_productie_grondstof_halffabrikaat,
CASE WHEN T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd] IS NULL
THEN (T0.[OnHand]/T2.[Nog_te_produceren])*30
ELSE ((T0.[OnHand]-T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd])/T2.[Nog_te_produceren])*30
END AS Dagen_voorraad_halffabrikaat_eindproduct,
CASE WHEN T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd] IS NULL
THEN (T0.[OnHand]/T1.[Nog_te_produceren])*30
ELSE ((T0.[OnHand]-T1.[Reeds_geproduceerd])/T1.[Nog_te_produceren])*30
END AS Dagen_voorraad_grondstof_halffabrikaat

FROM OITM T0

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT T1.[ItemCode],
SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]*T1.[BaseQty]) AS Geplande_productie,
CASE WHEN SUM(T0.CmpltQty) IS NULL THEN SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]*T1.[BaseQty]) ELSE SUM(T0. [CmpltQty]*T1.[BaseQty]) END AS Reeds_geproduceerd,
CASE WHEN SUM(T0.CmpltQty) IS NULL THEN SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]*T1.[BaseQty]) ELSE SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]*T1.[BaseQty])-SUM(T0.[CmpltQty]*T1.[BaseQty]) END AS Nog_te_produceren
FROM OWOR T0
INNER JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T0.DueDate <= getdate()+30
AND (T0.[Status] LIKE 'p'
OR T0.[Status] LIKE 'r')
GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode]
) AS T1
ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT T0.[ItemCode],
SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]) AS Geplande_productie,
SUM(T0.[CmpltQty]) AS Reeds_geproduceerd,
SUM(T0.[PlannedQty])-SUM(T0.[CmpltQty]) AS Nog_te_produceren
FROM OWOR T0
INNER JOIN WOR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T0.DueDate <= getdate()+30
AND (T0.[Status] LIKE 'p'
OR T0.[Status] LIKE 'r')
GROUP BY T0.[ItemCode]
) AS T2
ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
```

I mentioned all the where clauses. If I red the linked page correct, that cant be the problem.

I also changed the table names and column names of the derived tables. Now all table names and column names are unique.

But still the same problem. When i delete the last two case statements in select, i do get all the output lines, but i dont see any problems in these case statements.

```
SELECT T0.[ItemCode],
T0.[ItemName],
CASE T0.[PrcrmntMtd] WHEN 'B' THEN 'Inkoop' ELSE 'Productie' END AS Verwervingsmethode,
T0.[OnHand] AS Voorraad_excl_grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond] AS Grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
CASE WHEN T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond] IS NULL
THEN T0.[OnHand]
ELSE T0.[OnHand]-T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond]
END AS Voorraad_incl_grondstof_reeds_verwerkt,
T6.[Nog_te_produceren_eind] AS Geplande_productie_halffabrikaat_eindproduct,
T3.[Nog_te_produceren_grond] AS Gereserveerd_voor_productie_grondstof_halffabrikaat,
CASE WHEN T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond] IS NULL
THEN 30*(T0.[OnHand]/T6.[Nog_te_produceren_eind])
ELSE 30*((T0.[OnHand]-T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond])/T6.[Nog_te_produceren_eind])
END AS Dagen_voorraad_halffabrikaat_eindproduct,
CASE WHEN T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond] IS NULL
THEN 30*(T0.[OnHand]/T3.[Nog_te_produceren_grond])
ELSE 30*((T0.[OnHand]-T3.[Reeds_geproduceerd_grond])/T3.[Nog_te_produceren_grond])
END AS Dagen_voorraad_grondstof_halffabrikaat

FROM OITM T0

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT T2.[ItemCode] AS ItemCode_grond,
SUM(T1.[PlannedQty]*T2.[BaseQty]) AS Geplande_productie_grond,
CASE WHEN SUM(T1.CmpltQty) IS NULL
THEN SUM(T1.[PlannedQty]*T2.[BaseQty])
ELSE SUM(T1.[CmpltQty]*T2.[BaseQty])
END AS Reeds_geproduceerd_grond,
CASE WHEN SUM(T1.CmpltQty) IS NULL
THEN SUM(T1.[PlannedQty]*T2.[BaseQty])
ELSE SUM(T1.[PlannedQty]*T2.[BaseQty])-SUM(T1.[CmpltQty]*T2.[BaseQty])
END AS Nog_te_produceren_grond
FROM OWOR T1
INNER JOIN WOR1 T2 ON T1.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
WHERE T1.DueDate <= getdate()+30
AND (T1.[Status] LIKE 'p'
OR T1.[Status] LIKE 'r')
GROUP BY T2.[ItemCode]
) AS T3
ON T0.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode_grond

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT T4.[ItemCode] AS ItemCode_eind,
SUM(T4.[PlannedQty]) AS Geplande_productie_eind,
SUM(T4.[CmpltQty]) AS Reeds_geproduceerd_eind,
SUM(T4.[PlannedQty])-SUM(T4.[CmpltQty]) AS Nog_te_produceren_eind
FROM OWOR T4
INNER JOIN WOR1 T5 ON T4.DocEntry = T5.DocEntry
WHERE T4.DueDate <= getdate()+30
AND (T4.[Status] LIKE 'p'
OR T4.[Status] LIKE 'r')
GROUP BY T4.[ItemCode]
) AS T6
ON T0.ItemCode = T6.ItemCode_eind
```

Comment: Do you  havea where clause you didn't mention?

Comment: if yes to question above:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: if you are sure of the counting of OITM, may be the alias name: for example you use T0 for OITM and OWOR, not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: Lets be sure.  First, post the output of `SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM OITM`.  Second, please post the Query Plan for your first query above.

Comment: Sample data would also be helpful to include.  I also believe that @tschmit007 may be onto something.  You should try changing your sub queries to have their own unique aliases and see if it doesn't solve your problem.